# Can I write a UDF for MySQL in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, user-defined-functions

I would like to have the option to call Python via MySQL stored procs.
For this reason I was wondering if I can use Python to write a UDF that I can call from MySQL.

If that's not possible what alternative way could I use to make this happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MySQL 5.0
docs say that a [trigger can call a
UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10), so that part seems possible.  Reviewing the source code of some UDF extensions would give you a good idea of the complexity involved.  You can find open source packages on the [MySQL UDF
repository](http://www.mysqludf.org).

I wish I had an easy answer to the "create a MySQL UDF in Python" part, but I don't know of a simple off-the-shelf way of doing it.

[Postgres has a PL/Python language](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/plpython.html) which lets you write procedures and functions
directly using Python inside the database.  This code may be the best guide for
figuring out how to plug Python into MySQL; however, to my knowledge nobody has accomplished this yet (but I'd love to be wrong).

*A few messy details of how this might be done:*

UDFs are shared objects which are loaded into the MySQL daemon, so to create
one you need to be able to generate C stubs which (among other things)
initialize the Python interpreter, load and compile your Python script into
bytecode, and then translate MySQL UDF arguments int a Python function call,
then translate the return value back.

For a simple UDF string function named `myfunc` the shared object would have the following functions:

```
// initialize state when 'myfunc' is loaded.
my_bool myfunc_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, ...)

// call myfunc, this would need to translate the args, invoke the
// python function, then return the string, may need to create and cache
// python sub-interpreters on the fly, etc
char *myfunc(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, ...)

// clean up the state when 'myfunc' is unloaded.
void myfunc_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid);
```

Since there may be several invocations of your UDF running at once on separate
threads, so you'd need to find
a way to either efficiently create and cache sub-interpreters on-demand within
the context of a single function call, or safely reuse a single interpreter
across multiple threads (with locking which may slow things down unacceptably).